# CONVERT NUMBERS IN 'WHERE' STATEMENT TO INCLUDE DASHES IN SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have quite a lot of numbers in `xxxxxxxxx` format that I need to put in a `WHERE` clause in SQL Server. However, SQL Server will only recognize them if they are in a `xxx-xx-xxxx` format.

How do I add in the dashes in to the where statement in sql?

In summary, in WHERE statement, I need:

```
xxxxxxxxx
```

to be recognized in this format:

```
xxx-xx-xxxx
```

Comment: If they are the format `xxx-xx-xxxx` then the values are *not* in a numerical data type and trying to compare them to one will result of n failure.

Comment: digits given to me like this: 123456789.  Field they are in are stored like this 123-45-6789.  Therefore, I need to pull these from where in a 123-45-6789 format.

Comment: I have never seen numbers stored with dashes in SQL Server. Are you sure they are numbers and not CHAR? Not VarChar nor NVarChar?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure of the sql language - however, I am trying out some of the suggested responses and getting error converting datatype varchar to bigint if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That format looks like a SSN, it should be stored as a char datatype. So your comparison will be between strings.

Here is an example comparing with that format:

```
declare @yourNumber varchar(20) = '123456789'
set @yourNumber = SUBSTRING(@yourNumber, 1, 3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@yourNumber, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@yourNumber, 6, 4)

select * 
from someTable
where SSN = @yourNumber
```

Another way would be to compare removing the "-" in the where, something like this:

```
select * 
from someTable
where replace(SSN, '-', '') = @yourNumber
```

Of course you'll need to adapt this to your case.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Comment: if it's a SSN, it should be encrypted.  never ever store a SSN as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

`STUFF()` or `Format()` would help here.

Note: `Format()` has some great features, but performance can suffer

**Example**

```
 Select WithFormat = format(convert(bigint,'123456789'),'000-00-0000')
       ,WithStuff  = stuff(stuff('123456789',6,0,'-'),4,0,'-')
```

**Returns**

```
WithFormat  WithStuff
123-45-6789 123-45-6789
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to store them with dashes... But anyway what are you using to select them? T-SQL or some language? Just use some variable to format the number with dashes before select.
Like so in T-SQL

```
declare @num bigint
select @num = 123456789

declare @s_num varchar(max)
select @s_num = FORMAT(@num,'###-##-##-####')
-- select @s_num

select * from [Table] where number = @s_num
```

Comment: If the first digit is zero, you will get unexpected results using the # in the FORMAT()

Comment: It's not clear what numbers can there be from the conditions :)

Comment: WHy an `varchar(MAX)` when the value is only 11 characters long?

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER.  I have no idea why the field is stored with dashes in the ssn.